# Print All Orders

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders

I can't print any orders with status that aren't "*Complete*". If I try to "*Print all*" in pending orders or others that isn't "*Complete*" it says:

> There are no printable documents related to selected orders.

Can someone tell me where I can find the method that fires the *Print All* action.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is the `massPrintAction()` in `[magento-root]/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` on `line 459`

**Edit:**
The `massPrintAction()` does get called, but I think that the function you are looking for is in the same file on `line 575` called `pdfdocsAction()`.

There are also a number of related actions in the area between these two.